# How to dynamically update my dataframe in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

Now I have a function to pick the right row from the data frame and add it to the new data frame. In order to display the data better, I hope to update the data frame dynamically through the shiny package for loop (that is,  update the dataframe every iteration)。I'd try many approaches but failed. Here are the minimal example.
ui:

```
ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sidebarSearchForm(label = "numbers you woudle to append",textId = "num",buttonId = "btn")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("dt_test")
        )
    )
)
```

server:

```
server = function(input, output) {
    num <- eventReactive(input$btn,input$num) # press the button to update value
    ls_vars <- reactiveValues(test_dt=data.frame())
    observeEvent(input$btn,{
        for (i in 1:5) {
            dt_1 <- data.frame(num(),num()) # view it as the new row  
            Sys.sleep(2)  # view it as the running time
            ls_vars$test_dt <- rbind(dt_1,ls_vars$test_dt)
            output$dt_test <- renderDataTable({ls_vars$test_dt})
        }}) 
}
```

Is there anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: I am still not sure about your question. What is it that needs to happen after the app is launched?

Comment: At present, its effect is to display output until the last iteration is finished, but I need it to display the result once **every iteration**